# How log/track coords of spell drop

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I am working on developing an addon that tracks ports in WoW, ie Transcendence, Demonic Circle. I am able to register the aura event. What I am trying to do now, is to log/track the coords of the portal. My end goal is to create an XML template to show an arrow that points to the port and changes color based on distance. Any help is appreciated, this is my first attempt at a real addon. Here is what I have so far:

```
local f = CreateFrame("Frame")
f:RegisterUnitEvent("UNIT_AURA", "player")

f:SetScript("OnEvent", function()
    local name, _, _, _, duration, expirationTime, _, _, _, spellId = AuraUtil.FindAuraByName('Transcendence', 'player', 'helpful')

    if name then
        -- Do a thing
    end
end)
```

Comment: the [gamedev](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) site of the network might worth a try

Comment: awesome thanks! I had no idea about that site :D

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery Also have a look [here.](https://wow.gamepedia.com/COMBAT_LOG_EVENT) There may be some useful info.

Comment: @AliDeym I don't see anything about the coords of where the spell landed, in the case of my question; where the port dropped

Comment: @Cid I posted there as well, thank you.

Comment: Please post each question on only one site in the StackExchange network, to help centralize the best answers in one place. If you'd like to ask this on GameDev.StackExchange, delete the copy here, or the other may be closed as a cross-post.

Comment: deleted on gamedev since this one gets more traffic

Answer (score 0):

For this particular problem, I was able to use the HereBeDragons library to `GetPlayerZonePosition()`. This allowed me to get the x,y coords along with the map id of where the spell was cast as it's an instant cast spell.

```
local hbd = LibStub("HereBeDragons-2.0")

function getPlayerPosition()
  local x, y, mapID = hbd:GetPlayerZonePosition()
  return mapID, x, y
end
```

Then using the event handlers I log the coords for where the spell was cast(eg the spot of the port) and then using the event handler to check for aura(eg long polling) I can update with the current position of the player.

```
f:SetScript("OnEvent", function(self, event, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
  local transendenceAura = AuraUtil.FindAuraByName('Transcendence', 'player', 'helpful')
  if (event == 'UNIT_SPELLCAST_SUCCEEDED' and arg1 == 'player' and (arg3 == 101643 or arg3 == 119996)) then
    mapID, x2, y2 = getPlayerPosition()
  else
    x2 = 0
    y2 = 0
  end
  if transendenceAura then
    mapID1, x1, y1 = getPlayerPosition()
  end
end)
```

Now I just need to work on calculating the distance between the two points in yards and rendering an XML arrow on the screen. But for now, this particular hurdle is finished :D